# Captive portal not working correctly on iOS 11

Tags: ios11, captiveportal

On iOS versions before iOS 11:
I connect to a wifi network, the captive portal splash page is presented, a presented button links to an app on the app store https://itunes.apple.com/etcetc, the button is pressed and the app store is opened iOS.

On iOS 11:
The app store is not opened into the foreground. The user has to press the home button to get the app store.

How do I open the app store in the foreground when pressing the app store link? 
This problem only happens in iOS 11.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We met the same problem, what we can do is filing a bug report to apple.

Please refer to the discussion here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/75498#221482